# Linker error in WINAPI code

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to compile the following code but I am getting linker errors. Thankyou to tell what I am missing.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.dll")

int main()
{
    return MessageBoxA(0,"Message","Warn",0x01);
}
```

`fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'user32.dll'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since LIB file is used to link against a DLL at compile-time, MessageBoxA resides in user32.dll and requires user32.lib for proper linking.
So change `user32.dll` to `user32.lib` in #pragma comment like

`#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")`